# what is the meaning of owns% in cassandra and how to change it?

Tags: cassandra

I've configured the cannsadra cluster (cassandra-1.1) of 4 instances.
I have 2 pc's and i'm running 2 instances at each pc.
The pc's are identical, and have 20G ram.
But, when I'm running nodetool it show me different Owns %. The question is WHY?

```
./bin/nodetool  -p 8001 ring

Note: Ownership information does not include topology, please specify a keyspace. 
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                     Token                                                                                                                                   51042355038140769519506191114765231718      
172.16.40.32    datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  11.12 KB        70.00%              0                                           
127.0.0.2       datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  11.31 KB        10.00%              17014118346046923173168730371588410572      
172.16.40.202   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  6.7 KB          10.00%              34028236692093846346337460743176821145      
127.0.0.3       datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  11.18 KB        10.00%              51042355038140769519506191114765231718
```

my free -m looks on both machines:

```
        total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         20119       9621      10497          0        281       7925
-/+ buffers/cache:       1414      18704
Swap:         2894          2       2892
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentage is determined by the token distribution across the nodes. The token range for Cassandra go from 0 to 2^127 (170141183460469231731687303715884105728). Your ring's tokens are not evenly distributed between 0 and 2^127 so that is why you have one node with 70% ownership. You can use `nodetool move` to get your ring in balance.

There is a simple python script on the [Cassandra wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Load_balancing) that will generate evenly balanced tokens. I also wrote a simple tool to help [visualize your ring topology](http://psanford.github.com/cassandra-visual-ring/).

Comment: Thanks, So from your answer each time I'm adding additional node into the cluster I should move all the nodes to the new initial token?